# python3 OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I try to make a chat on Python3. Here is my code:

```
import socket
import threading

print("Server starts working")

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 57054))
sock.listen(2)

conn, addr = sock.accept()


def get_message():
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        if len(data) != 0:
            print("Some guy: ", data)


def send_message():
    while True:
        message = input()
        if len(message) != 0:
            message = str.encode(message)
            sock.send(message)
            print("You: ", message)


def run():
    get_message_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_message())
    send_message_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_message())

    get_message_thread.daemon = True
    send_message_thread.daemon = True

    get_message_thread.start()
    send_message_thread.start()


run()

sock.close()
```

But after the execution and sending a message from other client I get an error message:

```
Server starts working
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ptrknvk/Documents/Study/Python/chat/chat.py", line 40, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/ptrknvk/Documents/Study/Python/chat/chat.py", line 30, in run
    get_message_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_message())
  File "/home/ptrknvk/Documents/Study/Python/chat/chat.py", line 15, in get_message
    data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've read, that there are some troubles with sock.accept(), but everything's alright here, as I think.

Comment: Don't use parentheses for `target`.  Change to `threading.Thread(target=get_message)`  If you use `threading.Thread(target=get_message())`, you are using what `get_message()` returns as a target, not `get_message` itself.  You need to do the same thing with `send_message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has many flaws. As zondo mentioned, you are incorrectly passing the target. They should be like threading.Thread(target=get_message). Second problem is, you should use conn (and not sock) for sending and receiving data. Third problem is, main thread was blocking at accept call and will wait for the connection. But soon as it accepts a connection, it will exit. From the main thread, you should wait for get_message_thread and send_message_thread. Try the modified code:

```
import socket
import threading

print("Server starts working")

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 57054))
sock.listen(2)

conn, addr = sock.accept()


def get_message():
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if len(data) != 0:
            print("Some guy: ", data)


def send_message():
    while True:
        message = input()
        if len(message) != 0:
            message = str.encode(message)
            conn.send(message)
            print("You: ", message)


def run():
    get_message_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_message)
    send_message_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_message)

    get_message_thread.daemon = True
    send_message_thread.daemon = True

    get_message_thread.start()
    send_message_thread.start()
    get_message_thread.join()
    send_message_thread.join()

run()

sock.close()
```